# C# how to set a hidden property using the "new" property?

Tags: c#, generics, tree

I have a class

```
public class MenuItem
{
    // This class have a lot of fixed properties that I can't change
    public string Foo { get; set; } 

    // Child items used to create a tree structure
    public IList<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And now I want to create a new class that inherits from `MenuItem` that will hold more data that I need.

```
public class MenuItemData<T> : MenuItem
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public new IList<MenuItemData<T>> Items { get; set; }
}
```

But to be able to have the tree structure, I need somehow to "change" the type of `Items` to be my new `MenuItemData<T>`, so I used `new`.

But then, the problem is that when I populate this tree structure with `MenuItemData<T>`, It only sets the value to the `IList<MenuItemData<T>> Items` and not the `IList<MenuItem> Items` which will be used to create the tree structure.

So I need somehow to set both `Items` for it to work... but I don't know how to do that.

What I tried to do is set the tree structure with the `IList<MenuItemData<T>> Items` and then traverse the tree and set the hidden property, but I also don't know how I can get the "new" property and set it's value to the hidden property (the "new" property inherits from the hidden property, so I should be able to set the value from one to the other).

Please notice that:

- I cannot change the `MenuItem` class.
- If there's a solution without the `new`, it will be ok too
- If the question is confusing, please let me know and I can give some examples on how I'm traversing the tree.

Comment: To start with, you can rename `Items` in `MenuItemData` class to something different, then problem will become clearer (since it's a separate property and is not related to parent `Items` property).

Comment: @Evk The `Items` in `MenuItemData` is the same `Items` from `MenuItem`, the only difference is that I want to add some new data on it to make some logic, but to render the tree structure, both properties represent the same thing

Comment: `IList<T>` is invariant interface, you may look at `IEnumerable<T>`, which is covariant in regards of `T` type parameter

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I understand what you mean, but I have no clue what to do with that information

Comment: But from language perspective - they are two different properties, so adding `new` only confuses yourself. If you have variable of type `MenuItemData<Something>` and set `Items` - it will set `MenuItemData.Items` property.  If you have variable of type `MenuItem` and set `Items` - it will set `MenuItem.Items`. They are two separate properties.

Comment: @Evk So your solution would be to change the name of the property, to something like `DataItems` and when setting the `DataItems`, also set `Items` with a cast?

Comment: You can do this yes, but note that in theory it's still possible to add an item to `MenuItem.Items` which is not `MenuItemData`, then your cast will fail. If you are fine with that then better continue using `new .. Items` property on child class, otherwise it will be even more confusing to use (not sure where to add an item: to Items or to DataItems).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a hidden property with a cast to the type with hidden property :

```cs
static void SetItems<T>(MenuItemData<T> menu, IList<MenuItemData<T>> items)
{
    menu.Items = items;
    ((MenuItem)menu).Items = items.Cast<MenuItem>().ToList();
}
```

Also, you can use the keyword `base` to access hidden property from derived class. In addition, the class `MenuItemDataList<T>` implement `IList<MenuItem>` and `IList<MenuItemData<T>>` :

```cs
public class MenuItemData<T> : MenuItem
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public new IList<MenuItemData<T>> Items
    {
        get => (MenuItemDataList<T>)base.Items;
        set => base.Items = new MenuItemDataList<T>(value);
    }
}

public class MenuItemDataList<T> : List<MenuItemData<T>>, IList<MenuItem>
{
    public MenuItemDataList(IList<MenuItemData<T>> items) : base(items)
    {}

    MenuItem IList<MenuItem>.this[int index]
    {
        get => this[index];
        set => this[index] = (MenuItemData<T>)value;
    }
    bool ICollection<MenuItem>.IsReadOnly => false;
    void ICollection<MenuItem>.Add(MenuItem item) => Add((MenuItemData<T>)item);
    bool ICollection<MenuItem>.Contains(MenuItem item) => item is MenuItemData<T> data && Contains(data);
    void ICollection<MenuItem>.CopyTo(MenuItem[] array, int arrayIndex) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    IEnumerator<MenuItem> IEnumerable<MenuItem>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    int IList<MenuItem>.IndexOf(MenuItem item) => item is MenuItemData<T> data ? IndexOf((MenuItemData<T>)item) : -1;
    void IList<MenuItem>.Insert(int index, MenuItem item) => Insert(index, (MenuItemData<T>)item);
    bool ICollection<MenuItem>.Remove(MenuItem item) => Remove((MenuItemData<T>)item);
}
```

Comment: But if I do `Items.Add`, it won't set the value in the base class (i.e. not calling the setter)

Comment: Yes, a solution can be a class `MenuItemDataList<T>` that inherit `List<MenuItem>` and implement `IList<MenuItemDataList<T>`.

Comment: See my edit, `Items.Add` will work with the new solution.

Comment: The first approach is exactly what I need, I didn't know that you could cast the variable you are assigning. The second approach I didn't test it, but looks ok too, but for my case, the first one solved the problem. Thanks!